# Divergent Curves and Complete Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm working on a problem in do Carmo's Riemannian geometry book (chapter 7, problem 5). He states that a *divergent curve* on a noncompact Riemannian manifold $M$ is a curve $\alpha: [0, \infty) \to M$ where given any compact $K \subset M$ we have there exists $T>0$ such that $\alpha(t) \not\in K$ for $t>T$.  Subsequently the length is defined in the usual sense for curves on a manifold:

$$
L(\alpha) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^\infty ||\alpha'(t)|| dt.
$$

The problem I'm trying to prove is

> Prove that a noncompact manifold is complete if and only if every divergent curve has unbounded (i.e. infinite) length.

The "forwards" direction of the proof is easy; I'm having trouble with the other direction.  If I assume that every divergent curve $\alpha$ has infinite length, how do I show completeness of the manifold?  I'm borrowing one strategy from [MIT OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/lecture-notes/chapter19.pdf) but I don't totally agree with their proof.  They claim that we can start with some arbitrary geodesic $\gamma:[0,\epsilon) \to M$ and assume that such a geodesic cannot be extended to the interval $[0,\infty)$.  The set $R$ of points $x$ on which $\gamma$ can be extended to $[0,x)$ is nonempty and bounded above, thus let $s = \sup R$.  Define a re-parameterization $\alpha(t) = \gamma(s(1-e^{-t}))$, which is defined on $[0,\infty)$ but is of finite length.  If we can show that $\alpha$ is a divergent curve we are done.

The problem I have with the proof in the link is that they claim that $\gamma$ approaches a point on the "boundary" of $M$, but I find this claim problematic since it's not clear how to define a boundary unless $M$ is embedded/immersed in some ambient space.  Ultimately I would like to show that $\alpha$ escapes every compact subset of $M$, but I'm starting to think this proof might be problematic.

Can anyone suggest a way to amend the above proof as stated, or provide an alternate proof strategy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider any geodesic of unit speed $ \gamma :[0,\epsilon )
\rightarrow M$ If $\gamma(t)$ goes to $q\in M$, then by considering
$B_\delta (q)$ we can extend the geodesic $\gamma : [0,\epsilon
+\delta )\rightarrow M$

If we can do same thing countably many and if we have $\gamma : [0, \infty)
 \rightarrow M$, then we have a completeness

And assume that $M$ is not complete So we have $\gamma : [0,\epsilon )\rightarrow M$ which
 can not be extended.

By reparametrization we have $\alpha(t) =\gamma (\epsilon
 (1-e^{-t})),\ t\in [0,\infty)$

If $
 \alpha (n)$ are in some compact set $K$ so it has a limit in $K$. It is a contradiction since $\gamma$ can not
 be extended. So any compact set does not contain all $\alpha (n)$ That is $\alpha$ is divergent curve
 If $\alpha$ has infinite length then it is a contradiction since $ {\rm length}\ \alpha =
 {\rm length}\ \gamma =\epsilon$

Comment: To be clear, you're using the fact that compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed, and that the set $\{\alpha(n)\}$ has a convergent subsequence/cluster point?

Comment: Yes If subsequence of $\{ \alpha(n)\}$ is in $K$ then it has convergent subsequence and its limit point is in $K$. Hence it is a contradiction